# How to track change in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, reverse-engineering

I am new with SQL database, I am build some Automation Tool in MS-Excel , which can read and write data in database contain 160 tables, this database is also write and read by other software(X).

my task is find all changes are done by other software(X), in database table. so same think I can be done with excel.

Practically It is hard to check one by one 160 table.

I really appreciate for help, I was Google on it but not found so much. 
sorry if any mistake in my question.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL or MySQL? You will want to remove the tag for whichever you are not using.

Comment: @ Leonidas199x I am use "MS SQL"

Comment: What is your SQL Server Edition? If you don't know, paste here the result of `select @@version`

Comment: If you use Enterprise Edition (or evaluation or developer) you can implement Change Data Capture in (CDC) SQL Server  - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx
If not then you basically have to have the other software to somehow log what is done to the tables, or to compare the contents of the database with what was last seen in your application.

Comment: @ sepupic  I run "select @@version" and answer is as "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (Intel X86)   Aug 19 2014 12:21:07   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7600: ) "

Comment: There are solutions "out of the box", but since you have **Express Edition** you cannot use them. I think your only option is writing triggers for every table of interest.

Comment: One possible method is to add CreatedOn, CreatedBy, ModifiedOn, ModifiedBy columns to every table and add table triggers to fill them on insert or update.  Then when the 'other software' uses certain dedicated users to logon, you can query those fields on those users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server Change Tracking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx) in SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.  See [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).aspx#Replication).